# get caret position relative to visible start of line

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, getselection

I know I can use the following line to get the offset of the caret (cursor position) relative to the current element:

```
offset = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
```

But sometimes the element will contain a lot of text, and the text will wrap.  How can I find the offset relative to the nearest wrap (if any)?

For instance, given the following text which is all in one element:

```
<p>abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz test</p>
```

Suppose it is automatically line-wrapped as follows:

```
abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz
test
   ^cursor before this 't'
```

If the cursor is between the "s" and "t" in test, the above code will assign a value of 30 (26 characters on 1st line, plus space, plus t,e, and s.) to offset.  But I want it to return 3 in this case: relative to the apparent start of the line, the cursor is only offset 3 ('t', 'e', and 's' come before the cursor.)

How can I accomplish this in plain, cross-platform javascript?

Update:

In case there is an easier way to accomplish what I am trying to do, here it is.  I have a table of elements that I am individually turning into content editable blocks. When the down arrow is released and I see that the arrow was moved to the end of the TD, I move the focus (and the content editable) to the next cell down.  However, I also need to position the cursor so it is below where it previously was on the previous line. I'm using a monospaced font, so just using the same offset as the previous apparent start of line would be sufficient.

Setting the entire table to be contentEditable doesn't work, because the behavior of the arrow keys isn't what I want.  For instance, when I press down at the bottom of the field, it moves the cursor to the start of the next field to the right, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: I would wrap each letter in a `<span>`, which does not apply any styles and query their positions one by one. If the `y` value changes, you have got a new line.

Comment: If using textareas instead is a possibility, you could use something like http://jsfiddle.net/gaqxxdjq/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range.prototype.getClientRects()` to obtain the bounding client rects for a range. If there is a text node wrapping around to a second line, for instance, its range will have rects for each line. You can create a ‘sentinel’ range just to read its rects, then adjust it in a loop until the rect’s top or bottom changes, wind it back a bit, and check out its position. Then compare its position to your starting point and you will have the line-relative offset.